# In App Purchase product

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Im working on client project. I need to test my product for In App Purchase. I created app details in itunes connect through my account. I used my client App name,icons,everything. But if finally i upload app from client account, Is anything error will come on the app name, icons,Availability date, etc.

Comment: You need to read the app submission docs. For in app purchases , there are some steps that are required to take care for uploading app.

Comment: After reading only i got this doubt.

Answer (score 0):

App names in iTunesConnect are like domain names: Once a name is 'registered' (i.e. used for an app) on one account, no one else can create an app on iTunesConnect with the same name.  You give no details about the error you see, so I guess this might be your problem.

To use the same app name for your client, you need to delete the app from your iTunesConnect account.  After some time --don't know how long-- the app name will become available again for someone else to use.  Then you can use it for your client's app.

Bottom line: Never use the real name, a client gave to an app, in iTunesConnect!